# copy-item With Alternate Credentials

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using the CTP of powershell v2. I have a script written that needs to go out to various network shares in our dmz and copy some files. However, the issue I have is that evidently powershell's cmdlets such as copy-item, test-path, etc do not support alternate credentials...

Anyone have a suggestion on how best to accomplish my task..?

Comment: Here is a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313/can-i-copy-files-to-a-network-place-from-a-script-or-the-command-line

Answer (score 49):

I have encountered this recently, and in the most recent versions of Powershell there is a new [BitsTransfer Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663885%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which allows file transfers using [BITS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968799%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and supports the use of the -Credential parameter.

The following sample shows how to use the BitsTransfer module to copy a file from a network share to a local machine, using a specified PSCredential object.

```
Import-Module bitstransfer
$cred = Get-Credential
$sourcePath = \\server\example\file.txt
$destPath = C:\Local\Destination\
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $sourcePath -Destination $destPath -Credential $cred
```

Another way to handle this is using the standard "net use" command. This command, however, does not support a "securestring" password, so after obtaining the credential object, you have to get a decrypted version of the password to pass to the "net use" command.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$networkCred = $cred.GetNetworkCredential()
net use \\server\example\ $networkCred.Password /USER:$networkCred.UserName
Copy-Item \\server\example\file.txt C:\Local\Destination\
```

Comment: Just chiming in, but I tried the BITS piece, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Do I need to do `Complete-BitsTransfer` to wait for it to finish, or is it synchronous by default?

Comment: Also, note that this doesn't work with locations like `\\server\C$`. See http://serverfault.com/q/512558/172060.

Comment: I do not think the BITS transfer works as you suggest. I am using powershell 2 and I still need to create a mapping with "net use" before using the BITS, otherwise it (quite obviously) says that the unc path does not exist. So in my script I do: net use to add path...bits...net use /delete

Answer (score 36):

Since PowerShell doesn't support "-Credential" usage via many of the cmdlets (*very* annoying), and mapping a network drive via WMI proved to be very unreliable in PS, I found  pre-caching the user credentials via a net use command to work quite well:

```
# cache credentials for our network path
net use \\server\C$ $password /USER:$username
```

Any operation that uses \\server\C$ in the path seems to work using the *-item cmdlets.

You can also delete the share when you're done:

```
net use \\server\C$ /delete
```

Comment: This seems to be the only option for `\\server\C$` style paths.

Comment: Even though it seem to work, each time I call `Copy-Item` from the network path it prompts me for username and password, which is quite annoying.

Comment: @JimAho It doesn't prompt username and password for me.

Answer (score 27):

PowerShell 3.0 now supports for credentials on the FileSystem provider. To use alternate credentials, simply use the Credential parameter on the New-PSDrive cmdlet

```
PS > New-PSDrive -Name J -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server001\sharename -Credential mydomain\travisj -Persist
```

After this command you can now access the newly created drive and do other operations including copy or move files like normal drive. here is the full solution:

```
$Source = "C:\Downloads\myfile.txt"
$Dest   = "\\10.149.12.162\c$\skumar"
$Username = "administrator"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Complex_Passw0rd" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $Password)

New-PSDrive -Name J -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Dest -Credential $mycreds -Persist
Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination "J:\myfile.txt"
```

Comment: Works perfect for me! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question but I'm just updating it for future finders.

**PowerShell v3 now supports using the -Credential parameter for filesystem operations.**

Hope this helps others searching for the same solution.

Comment: It's seem that `-credential` parameter is supported only for New-PsDrive for file system provider. With `copy-item` on v3 stil doesn't work.

Comment: Right, that's because copy-item works against PSDrives. You have to remount the drive under different credentials, or create a new PSDrive to the same remote resource but this can fail sometimes due to underlying O/S constraints (namely, using differing network credentials for the same remote resource in the same session.)

Answer (score 6):

I would try to map a drive to the remote system (using 'net use' or WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive, both methods support credentials) and then use copy-item.

Comment: This is the best answer because the filesystem provider (and thus copy-item) does not support credentials.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my script that runs as LocalSystem on a machine, but needs credentials of a domaim user to access a network file location.  It allows you to store the user's password in a "safe-ish" encrypted file; that can only be read by the user that wrote it.

Setting and changing the password is done by copying a file with the plaintext password in it to the machine.  When the script is next run it reads the password, encrypts it, then deletes the plaintext password.

```
$plaintext_password_file = 'C:\plaintext.txt' # Stores the password in plain text - only used once, then deleted
$encryted_password_file = 'C:\copy_pass.txt'  # Stores the password in "safe" encrypted form - used for subsequent runs of the script
                                              #   - can only be decrypted by the windows user that wrote it
$file_copy_user = 'OURDOMAIN\A_User'

# Check to see if there is a new plaintext password
if (Test-Path $plaintext_password_file)
{
    # Read in plaintext password, convert to a secure-string, convert to an encrypted-string, and write out, for use later
    get-content $plaintext_password_file | convertto-securestring -asplaintext -force | convertfrom-securestring | out-file $encryted_password_file
    # Now we have encrypted password, remove plain text for safety
    Remove-Item $plaintext_password_file
}


# Read in the encrypted password, convert to a secure-string
$pass = get-content $encryted_password_file | convertto-securestring

# create a credential object for the other user, using username and password stored in secure-string
$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $file_copy_user,$pass

# Connect to network file location as the other user and map to drive J:
New-PSDrive -Name J -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\network\file_directory" -Credential $credentials

# Copy the file to J:
Copy-Item -Force -Verbose -Path "C:\a_file.txt" -Destination "J:\"
```

*As an extra refinement: The username could also be encrypted as well, rather than hardcoded.*

Answer (score 2):

I know that [PowerShell 3 supports this out of the box](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/21/improving-the-filesystem-provider-through-community-feedback.aspx) now, but for the record, if you're stuck on PowerShell 2, you basically have to either use the legacy `net use` command (as suggested by several others), or [the Impersonation module that I wrote](http://huddledmasses.org/using-alternate-credentials-with-the-filesystem-in-powershell/) awhile back specifically to address this.

Answer (score 2):

The newer verion of PowerShell handles this and the MS Documentation has a great example [of copying a file with different credentials here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1#example-5--copy-a-file-to-a-remote-computer)

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server02" -Credential "Contoso\User01"
Copy-Item "D:\Folder002\" -Destination "C:\Folder002_Copy\" -ToSession $Session
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blogs.technet.com/brad_rutkowski/archive/2008/09/26/using-invoke-command-to-launch-a-script-on-a-remote-computer-which-connects-to-network-resources.aspx) is a post where someone got it to work. It looks like it requires a registry change.

Comment: That guy is double hopping within the same domain. I need to be able to specify an account as I am accessing files on a different domain altogether...

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/connecting-to-a-network-folder-with-username-password-in-powershell) addresses a very related issue that may help [using network shares in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/connecting-to-a-network-folder-with-username-password-in-powershell).

Answer (score 0):

Bringing this back from the dead again. I got around a similar credentials problem by wrapping the .ps1 in a batch file and doing the Win7, Shift + r.Click RunAs. If you wanted to, you can also use PsExec thus:

```
psexec.exe /accepteula /h /u user /p pwd cmd /c "echo. | powershell.exe -File script.ps1"
```

Answer (score -1):

> that evidently powershell's cmdlets such as copy-item, test-path, etc do not support alternate credentials...

It looks like they do here, copy-item certainly includes a -Credential parameter.

```
PS C:\> gcm -syn copy-item
Copy-Item [-Path] <String[]> [[-Destination] <String>] [-Container] [-Force] [-Filter <String>] [-I
nclude <String[]>] [-Exclude <String[]>] [-Recurse] [-PassThru] [-Credential <PSCredential>] [...]
```

Comment: I keep receiving a error message stating -credential is not supported

Comment: TechNet (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315340.aspx) says "This parameter is not supported by any providers installed with Windows PowerShell." So they're too lazy to implement it and just expect anyone creating a new provider to do it.  :(

Comment: To ship is to choose ;)  The good news is they finally chose to implement it in PS3

Answer (score -6):

You should be able to pass whatever credentials you want to the -Credential parameter. So something like:

$cred = Get-Credential

[Enter the credentials]

Copy-Item -Path $from -Destination $to -Credential $cred

Comment: I keep receiving a error message stating -credential is not supported

Comment: I suspect it is an issue with unc pathing then.

Comment: well, this is the error...

Test-Path : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The provider does not support the use of credentials. Please perform the operation again without specifying credentials.

Comment: and the UNC looks like this...

\\ip\Logs