# How to copy the files from local system to the remote server by using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I'm running the command which i have shown you the image and its giving that error

Please suggest me on this
Actually am trying to copy the build from local system to the remote server by using powershell scirpt

and i want to copy the files from on remote server to the other remote server  by using local system

please provide me solutions for this and what are the requirements for this

Comment: what image are you talking about :) ? It's always best if you show what code you already have, so we can help to improve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the copy-item

```
copy-item -path "Your\path\to\folderorfile" -destination "\\servernameorip\dest\location\"
```

if you have different credentials on the destination server, you can either trick windows by creating a local account using same name and password on your m[copy with different credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612015/copy-item-with-alternate-credentials)

Comment: Hi,

But am getting the following error

PS C:\Windows\system32> Copy-Item "C:\Rakesh\INT_ASIA_AP2_20140725.2.zip" -Destination "\\10.7.239
Copy-Item : The network path was not found.
At line:1 char:10
+ Copy-Item <<<<  "C:\Rakesh\INT_ASIA_AP2_20140725.2.zip" -Destination "\\10.7.239.15\\d$"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

can u plz suggest

Comment: Your path is not correct : "C:\Rakesh\INT_ASIA_AP2_20140725.2.zip" please check.