# Copy-item Powershell not working on windows 11

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting, copy-item, superuser

I executed this copy-item command line on windows 11:

```
Copy-Item -Path '//c/shared/file.xml' -Destination '\\REMOTE-PC\c$\testFolder' -Force
```

and It gives me unauthorized access message.

[image]

My user has full control and the same line command is working in Windows 10. Something changed in the new version of Windows. Any idea?

Error Message:

> Copy-Item : Access is denied At line:1 char:1 + Copy-Item -Path
> '//source-Pc/shared/file.xml' -Destination '\dest-pc\c$ ... +
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
> ```

Comment: May be double hop authentication issues

Comment: Try one of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612015/copy-item-with-alternate-credentials

Comment: please post the FULL error msg _as text_. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Sorry my bad. Here is attached the error message as text.

Comment: Please update your post with the error, not in the comments, properly formatted. This doesn't seem like a PowerShell issue. I would suggest asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Seems like a permissions issue. Is the shell elevated? Can you copy the file locally? Can you copy it to any other PC? Those are the type of questions I have just by looking at this.

Comment: Why `-Recurse` if you are copying a single file? Also, why different slashes in source and destination? Are you trying to copy a file from one remote location to another? Does `Get-Content '//c/shared/file.xml'` work?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Yes I can copy the file locally and using a windows explorer as well. I can use the same copy-item line code to other pcs with Windows 10 or lower versions.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to copy a file from a remote server to a remote workstation. -Recurse is used for multiple files but I tried to simplify the issue in only one command.