# Copy files to network computers on windows command line

Tags: windows, networking, scripting

I am trying to create a script on Windows which when run on an admin PC:

1. Copies a folder from the admin PC into a group of network PCs by specifying the ip address / range
2. For each destination PC, Navigate into the folder and run another script file.

Using the method described by seanyboy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313/can-i-copy-files-to-a-network-place-from-a-script-or-the-command-line):

```
net use \\{dest-machine}\{destfolder} {password} /user:{username}
copy {file} \\{dest-machine}\{destfolder}
```

I'm not sure on how i can write a 'for' loop to go through each 'dest-machine' and perform step 2. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25):

check Robocopy:

`ROBOCOPY \\server-source\c$\VMExports\ C:\VMExports\ /E /COPY:DAT`

make sure you check what robocopy parameter you want. this is just an example. 
type `robocopy /?` in a comandline/powershell on your windows system.

Comment: this is what I'm looking for!

Comment: How to provide username and password?

Comment: `NET USE \\RemoteServerName\IPC$ /u:server\user *password* 
robocopy \\Source\ \\RemoteServerName\DestinationDir\ /XD * /Z /MIR /LOG+:c:\temp\log.log
NET USE \\RemoteServerName\IPC$ /D`

Answer (score 16):

Below command will work in command prompt:

```
copy c:\folder\file.ext \\dest-machine\destfolder /Z /Y
```

To Copy all files:

```
copy c:\folder\*.* \\dest-machine\destfolder /Z /Y
```

Comment: what does /Z /Y means here ?

Comment: `/Z` - Copies networked files in restartable mode. 
`/L` - If the source is a symbolic link, copy the link to the target                instead of the actual file the source link points to.

Comment: So what does the /A mean?

Comment: It's a filter to copy only text files

Comment: try copy /? you will get details about all switches

Comment: COPY is old and deprecated. It was replaced with XCOPY. Which was replaced with ROBOCOPY. Use ROBOCOPY, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17286034/822870) above.

Answer (score 5):

Why `for`? What do you want to iterate? Try this.

```
call :cpy pc-name-1
call :cpy pc-name-2
...

:cpy
net use \\%1\{destfolder} {password} /user:{username}
copy {file} \\%1\{destfolder}
goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding step 2., check manual for psexec command (sysinternal tools)

Comment: Great advice. The sysinternals tools are very usefull.