# How to copy file from Network path to controller machine in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-module

Let's assume I have a textfile in some **network path**

EX: **\cr-ampd-a01.abcd.loc\BulkFolder\textfile.txt**

How to copy that file to my controller machine in **ansible**

**Note:** I can access it by (WIN+R and that path) then it pops up for credentials to access.

**This is the sample code with win_copy**

```
- name: copy from network to controller
  win_copy:
    src: \\cr-ampd-a01.abcd.loc\BulkFolder\textfile.txt
    dest: C:\Temp\OTW\Mastapps
    remote_src: yes
    become: yes
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: XXX\Uxxxxxx
    ansible_become_pass: PasswordHere
```

Error with this code is: Cannot copy src file as it does not exit

**Another with net_get**

```
  - name: copy from network to controller
    net_get:
      src: \\cr-ampd-a01.abcd.loc\BulkFolder\textfile.txt
      dest: C:\Temp\OTW\Mastapps
      ansible_network_os: "eos"
      remote_src: True
      become: True
    vars:
      ansible_become_user: XXX\Uxxxxxx
      ansible_become_pass: PasswordHere
```

**Error here: ansible_network_os must be specified on this host**

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

You try to copy a file from a CIFS resource. I'm relative sure that this isn't working with `copy` or `win_copy` because they are used to copy file on that (physical) machine. Because CIFS is a protocol like HTTP and FTP you need a client to get the file from the remote machine. As you also wrote, you need to identify yourself with some credentials, the `win_copy` task doesnt have that option.

One option could be - mount the network device to -for example- N:/ or something like that and use then win_copy with N:/source.txt - in that case the N:-drive is like C:/ or D:/ a known path on the machine. Have a look at `win_share` - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_share_module.html

Another option is to call a local CIFS client via command like `command: copy //server/path/file c:/file` or robocopy, but that isn't easy to be idempotent. See [Copy files to network computers on windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523520/copy-files-to-network-computers-on-windows-command-line)

`net_get` is useful to copy files from "network devices" - please have a look at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_index.html#platform-options for a list of supported platforms. As of the list - I would say coping from a CIFS-share is not supported by `net_get`.